# how to make auto generated primary key following our pattern in mvc code first approach

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, model-view-controller, code-first

i want to take roll no as a ID of student class and i want it should generate like **Student-(GUID)**

```
 public int ID { get; set; }
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why don't you make random numbers based on time?

Answer (score 0):

IF you want to insert student id like Student-(GUID) in your DB for this purpose you have to change your id from int to string .

```
public string ID {get;set;}
```

Now In your Controller take a string Variable like this

```
  public ActionResult ActionName(Formcollection form,DataTableName TableObject)
    {
    string student_id="Student-("+form["ID"]+")";
    String SQL="";
    SQL= " INSERT INTO TABLENAME (ID) VALUES ('"+student_id+"') ;"
    //eXECUTE YOUR QUERY 
    return view();
    }
```